# Eclipse Exporting to jar ignores Manifest class path: directive

Tags: java, eclipse, export, manifest

I am trying to use the Eclipse export function to create a jar file to be deployed in an Axis2 deployment in Tomcat. When I have source code projects, I can export this jar, rename it to aar, and it works fine. All the classes from all the projects are present inside that exported jar.

Now I convert a few of those projects to jar files (they form a library). The primary project now points to these library jars as external jars in the build path. It builds fine. Now I want to export the same type of jar file from this primary project that no longer has access to the projects containing the library source code.

SOO...I followed these instructions to create my own Manifest.txt file that would point to these external jars using the Class-Path directive. The line appears as follows:

```
Class-Path: file1.jar ../../libraryJars/file2.jar
```

So I follow the usual export to jar (not runnable of course; there is NO main here!) with the option to use my Manifest file and the Class-Path directive in that manifest is ignored. I look inside the created jar and the only classes I find are from the primary project. All those classes in the external jars were NOT loaded.

How do I get the classes inside the external jars to be exported with the classes in the primary project when creating this jar? I understood that using the Manifest.txt approach was the way to do this. Perhaps it only works when making a runnable jar (which I cannot do)?

I do NOT want to use something as messy as ANT. If I have to resort to script files to accomplish this task I will just do the copies with a bat file.

Comment: Can you simplify your question? If you want to export files from the external jars that you are using, then I am not sure how you can do that. But if you want the jars to be part of the export, create a META-INF/lib folder and put jars in there.....or create a folder, put your external jars in it and add it to the Build path and export.

Comment: Brian, accept more of the answers given to previous questions.

Comment: I want the class files in the external jars to be part of the exported (but non-executable) jar. I do not want to place copies of the external jars in each project in a META-INF/lib directory which I understand might work. What I currently have is a separate folder containing the external jars which is part of the build path for all projects (otherwise the projects wouldn't build). However, using Eclipse 'export jar' tool, even with a custom manifest.txt with the Class-Path directive does NOT include the classes in those external jars in the exported jar.

Comment: For Francis Upton. I did this for the truststore case; not exactly as the answer but through the dialog exchange. The android graphics case is still an enigma. For this case I believe it is not possible unless one wants to export a runnable jar.

Comment: The only way I could solve this (without making multiple copies of the same jars in a libs directory for every project) was to use an ANT script. I did simplify the script by assuming that Eclipse generated the class files.